# .net semaphore task cleanup on exit

Tags: c#, semaphore

I have code that processes a configurable amount of messages at a time.  A semaphore is used to ensure that only a certain number of tasks are running at a time.  Normally when running a semaphore, I would capture all the threads and ensure that all were completed at the end.  In this case, I could have thousands of them depending on how long the application was running.  I feel like if the app is requesting to stop that I should wait till all my threads are cleaned up to exit out of the ListenAsync method below.

```
public abstract class ContinuousListener
{
    private readonly ListenerOptions _listenerOptions;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

    public abstract Task ProcessMessageAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    public ContinuousListener(IOptions<ListenerOptions> listenerOptions)
    {
        _listenerOptions = listenerOptions.Value;
        _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(_listenerOptions.MaxConcurrentMessages);
    }

    public async Task ListenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
           await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

           var taskToWaitToCancel = ProcessSingleMessageAsync(cancellationToken);
        
           await Task.Delay(_listenerOptions.MessageDelay, cancellationToken);
       }
    }

    private async Task ProcessSingleMessageAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            await ProcessMessageAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Log Exception and continue running
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a pattern for cleaning up those tasks that I could use for taskToWaitToCancel?  Adding them to a list would end up having a lot of tasks that are completely done and just eat up memory.  I thought about writing a repo type class to keep track of current tasks.  IE add and delete methods for tasks and then call cancel on it which would iterate over all the tasks and make sure they all ended there work.

Comment: Why do you think they require cleaning up? Isn't cancellation enough?

Comment: Is cancellation enough?  That could be the answer, but just exiting and not waiting on them to say they were properly cancelled doesn't seem right.  So it's really just a feeling of it being improper is why I think it should be cleaned up.